# Component won't display just its own HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript

The stock Angular `app.component.html`

```
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * * The content below * * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * is only a placeholder * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * and can be replaced. * * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * Delete the template below * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * to get started with your project! * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * -->

<style>
 /* 
    Lots of unrelated stock Angular CSS
 */
</style>



   <!-- Lots of unrelated HTML-->


    <a routerLink="/employee-form" class="card" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
      <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" fill="#000000"><g><rect fill="none" height="24" width="24"/></g><g><g><path d="M14.73,13.31C15.52,12.24,16,10.93,16,9.5C16,5.91,13.09,3,9.5,3S3,5.91,3,9.5C3,13.09,5.91,16,9.5,16 c1.43,0,2.74-0.48,3.81-1.27L19.59,21L21,19.59L14.73,13.31z M9.5,14C7.01,14,5,11.99,5,9.5S7.01,5,9.5,5S14,7.01,14,9.5 S11.99,14,9.5,14z"/><polygon points="10.29,8.44 9.5,6 8.71,8.44 6.25,8.44 8.26,10.03 7.49,12.5 9.5,10.97 11.51,12.5 10.74,10.03 12.75,8.44"/></g></g></svg>
      <span>Open Employee Form</span>
      <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z"/></svg>
    </a>




   <!-- Lots of unrelated HTML-->



<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

When I place my extra `a` tag:

```
   <a routerLink="/employee-form" class="card" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
      <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" fill="#000000"><g><rect fill="none" height="24" width="24"/></g><g><g><path d="M14.73,13.31C15.52,12.24,16,10.93,16,9.5C16,5.91,13.09,3,9.5,3S3,5.91,3,9.5C3,13.09,5.91,16,9.5,16 c1.43,0,2.74-0.48,3.81-1.27L19.59,21L21,19.59L14.73,13.31z M9.5,14C7.01,14,5,11.99,5,9.5S7.01,5,9.5,5S14,7.01,14,9.5 S11.99,14,9.5,14z"/><polygon points="10.29,8.44 9.5,6 8.71,8.44 6.25,8.44 8.26,10.03 7.49,12.5 9.5,10.97 11.51,12.5 10.74,10.03 12.75,8.44"/></g></g></svg>
      <span>Open Employee Form</span>
      <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z"/></svg>
    </a>
```

To my new `employee-form.component.html` everything works fine, except for the fact that I want my `a` to my custom component to show only its HTML:

```
<form #employeeForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(employeeForm.value)">
  <div>
    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" ngModel>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="employeeId">Employee Id:</label>
    <input type="text" id="employeeId" name="employeeId" ngModel>
  </div>
  <button type="button" (click)="submitForm(employeeForm.value)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

However, it just shows the component on the existing screen.

`app.component.html` seems to be configured correctly. My routing seems to work find because my component appears and submits data to my API just fine.

I understand the idea of having components and it being a SPA, but in Angular surely you still want to post to new pages on a button click with none of the previous HTML, how is this accomplished?

Comment: This is how routing works. It inserts the navigated-to content under the `router-outlet`. If you want this entire page to be replaced, you need to route to a parent `router-outlet`.

Comment: Or, I guess in this situation, since this is the top-most router, the content that you want to navigate away from (the default HTML) should become a sibling component to the component that you want to navigate to. Then as you navigate between the two, each will replace the other under the `router-outlet` as you navigate.

Comment: Hey guys, this produces the same result. I made App folder containing app data the child of employee-form and got the same result.

Comment: Not a sibling in the same folder. I mean they should be together in the routing configuration.

Comment: @Carcigenicate can you add a little code block sample as to what you mean by together in the same routing configuration, or just a link to a documentation describing such? That would be a life saver.

Comment: If you search for "Angular Routing", you'll find their official documentation. There will be a file called something like `app-routing.module.ts`, and in there are where routing configurations are added.